# distinguish beetween alt and esc keypress in ncurses

Tags: c, keypress, alt

I am developing a C application using ncurses library in linux. my program cant distinguish between Alt  and Esc keypresses. both return 27!
can you help me how I can distinguish between the two?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

[NCurses and ESC,ALT keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977395/ncurses-and-esc-alt-keys)

Can't try it right now, though. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had already seen that. But didn't know what ERR means. could you please provide an example for me? thanks (i think even without using ncurses u can provide an example. am i right?) thanks again

Comment: ncurses timeout does the job very well. timeout(1);
            ch=getch();
            if(ch=='d')
            {...} thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You need to incorporate a short delay after the `^[` in order to see if there are further characters incoming. If not, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> has been pressed.

Comment: I don't know how to do that! do u mean using sleep/usleep ? could you kindly provide an example?